# Xubuntu. Wireless network disappears!

Tags: wireless

After installing Security Onion with Xubuntu(12.4.3-20130904.iso) on my machine my wireless network disappears completely. It's not visible in Network Settings with the icon in the bar also gone!? Any help is appreciated. Thanks, D.

Answer (score 3):

You can start the icon in the bar manually in a terminal by:

```
nm-applet
```

Security Onion is a separate distro based on xubuntu, so i think they use their own tools to manage the wireless interface. Here are a few things you can try:

**Check if your wireless interface is recognized as a wireless interface by:**

```
iwconfig
```

it should output something like this:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=14 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

**Check if your wireless interface is soft or hard blocked:**

```
rfkill list wlan
```

Possible output:

```
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: yes
```

Hard blocked means it is blocked by a hardware switch on your device.
Soft Blocked means an application (like Network Manager) is blocking it, as in my case.

**Unblock blocked wireless device:**

```
rfkill unblock wlan
```

It's obvious you can't unblock a hardware switch, besides with magic =)

**Check if your wireless interface is managed by Network Manager:**

```
nm-tool
```

In case of yes output looks like this:

```
- Device: wlan0 ---------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        8C:A9:82:52:CA:2A

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes
```

If no, you see `State: unavailable`:

```
- Device: wlan0 ---------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        8C:A9:82:52:CA:2A

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes
```

**Check if your wireless interfaces is not in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:**

Network Manager is not managing an interface that is listed in this file.

**Check if your wireless interface in not down:**

To up the interface invoke in terminal (assumed that wlan0 is your wireless interface):

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

If something give errors please add them to your question.